# Can I quickly create a playlist containing the results of a YouTube Music search?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-music

There's a YouTube music channel that features music from video game consoles. I'm only interested in music from from one console, so I use that console's name as a filter when searching the channel.

This gives me the search results I want, but unfortunately, once a song I select from the results finishes playing, the next song YouTube plays will not correspond to the next song in the search results, and in fact, may not even be from the same YouTube channel.

I can add the search results one by one to a playlist by clicking the more menu (3 dots) on each, but that's a lot of work.

Is there an easy way to create a playlist containing the results of a YouTube Music search?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Chrome browser extension [Multiselect for YouTube](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei?pli=1)
to select all the videos you want and then click the "..." icon in the panel at the bottom of the page to add them to a new playlist.  Also works for moving all "watch later" videos to a new playlist so you can add another 5K watch later videos.

> #### [Multiselect for YouTube](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/multiselect-for-youtube/gpgbiinpmelaihndlegbgfkmnpofgfei?pli=1)
>
> ##### Overview
>
> Move, sort, and copy videos in your playlists faster and easier.
>
> This extension will save you a lot of time managing your playlists. The operation has been simplified so that you can complete your tasks even faster.
> Additional features you've been waiting for.
>
> ✔️ Supports the new interface Manifest V3
> ✔️ The user experience has been redesigned from the ground up
> ✔️ Same display dark/light as in YouTube™
> ✔️ Selected videos are clearly highlighted
> ✔️ Icon button to toggle multiple selection on/off
> ✔️ Action bar
> ✔️ Context menu
>  Keyboard navigation
>  Copy, cut and paste videos
> ✨ Find duplicates
>  Select videos with title filter